# How to use wildcard in SSRS Report Builder Expression for URL

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I'm setting up an Action for a Text Box to open a file using Go To URL action.  The URL includes a DataSet Field in the expression, but I also need to wildcard in the expression to account for variable on the end of the file name.  One of the specific files I am trying to open is named B121597-9.pdf.  I want to use the DataSet Field Fields!item.Value to represent "B121597" portion of the filename and a wildcard expression to represent the "-9.pdf" portion of the name, as this portion will vary.

This is what I have tried:

```
 ="\\Server\Drive\Folder\Folder\" + Fields!item.Value + "\" + Fields!item.Value + "%"
```

But it returns the following:

```
 \\Server\Drive\Folder\Folder\B121597\B121597%
```

If I try:

```
 ="\\Server\Drive\Folder\Folder\" + Fields!item.Value + "\" + Fields!item.Value + "-9.pdf"
```

It works fine, but it doesn't account for the filename variation

Comment: where does the -9.pdf come from? it's a file name.. so you must know what the name is already right?

Comment: The file name for the particular file used in the example is B121597-9.pdf.  However, the -9 is a version number that will change as the file is updated over time.  So I need URL hyperlink to find the look for just the B121597 portion of the file name.  I see that % can be used a a wildcard in report builder expressions for Like statments (i.e. LIKE "B121957%"), but it doesn't seem to work directly in the URL address expression.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want the way you want to do it. What you will have to do is figure out the file name in your dataset first and then point to that in your report. If using SQLserver.. read the directory to get a list of files and figure out the one you need and show the full file name.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the full filename is not available in the SQL dataset.  Only the first part of the file name (i.e. B121957), which I am currently pulling from the dataset.  The last part of the filename, which varies, only exist in the filename outside of the SQL database.  That's why I am looking for a way to use a wildcard character for this part of the filename.

Comment: Yes. But you can use sql server to look in a folder for files using wildcards.. xp_fileexists can be used to check if files exist in the folder etc. I'm sure you can narrow it down to a single file in your data set